# What is $\sqrt {5 - \sqrt {13 + \sqrt {48}}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't figure out how to solve this, I don't really know how or where to find the solution, even the same problems just to figure out, but I didn't find anything. Please help.
$$
  \sqrt {5 - \sqrt {13 + \sqrt {48}}}
$$

I was thinking just to use a calculator, but I am not sure about this.
Any advices, any links would help very much, Thanks!!!

$$
  \left(\sqrt {5 - \sqrt {13 + \sqrt{48}}}\right) = {?}
$$
How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to figure out, exactly? Whether this number can be written in a simpler form?

Comment: When you write $\sqrt{4}8$, do you mean $\sqrt{4}\times 8 =16$ or $\sqrt{48}$?

Comment: @Kusma \sqrt {48}} Sorry i fixed

Comment: Considering the user mentions using a calculator, they apparently want to *evaluate* the expression to get a decimal.

Comment: @Sambo I think so, i guess i have to simplify or, there is no multiply and i never seen before, maybe somebody knows how to

Comment: First write $\sqrt{48} = 2\sqrt{12}$, and later write $\sqrt{12} = 2 \sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint to get you started: 
$$\sqrt{13 + \sqrt{48}} = \sqrt{(\sqrt{12})^2 + (\sqrt{1})^2 + 2\sqrt{12}\sqrt{1}}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{5 - \sqrt{12} - 1}$ = $\sqrt{3 - \sqrt{12} + 1}$ = $\sqrt3 - 1$

Comment: Thank you very much, thats really easy, you are the best

Answer (score 3):

The following method is often useful in similar exercises:

Find $a,b$ such that $\left(a+b\sqrt3\right)^2=13+4\sqrt{3}.$ This leads to the system  $$\left \{
\begin{array}{1}
 a^2+3b^2&=13\\
ab&=2
\end{array}\right.$$
with two solutions $(a,b)=(\pm1,\pm2).$ Consequently $\sqrt{13+\sqrt{48}}=1+2\sqrt3.$

Once again this method: $$(c+d\sqrt3)^2=5-\left(1+2\sqrt3\right)$$ leads to
$$\left \{
\begin{array}{1}
 c^2+3d^2&=4\\
cd&=-1
\end{array}\right.$$

and we have $(c,d)=(\pm1,\mp1)$.
We can write $$\sqrt{5-\sqrt{13+\sqrt{48}}}=-1+\sqrt3,$$ as the square root is non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

Since we have $48=3\times 16$, we can write $$\sqrt{5-\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}}$$